# iOS: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I inherited an old app and I'm trying to launch it on physical device and it gets terminated on launch and it says on console

> "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch".

This app launches and works fine on simulator (iOS 8.4 or iOS 9.0) and but when I try to run it on my iPad (with Dev prov profile), it returns this exception. I searched a lot and tried to use all suggested solutions posted on this forum but I had not luck so far! these are what I tried:

```
retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegate");//in main.m
[self.window setRootViewController:myMainViewController];//in DidFinishingLaunching...
```

the window and app delegate are in mainWindow.xib looks connected properly as well.

Any idea or thought what is wrong?
I use Xcode 7.1 and set Deployment Target to 8.0, on simulators it works fine.

Comment: Go into Storyboard, find the root viewController, and make sure the 'Is Initial View Controller' option is checked (under the 'View Controller' options - 4th tab from the left).

Comment: Also: Make sure that myMainViewController is not nil. Could it be that the storyboard is initialised correctly but the rootViewController is overwritten with a nil value?

Comment: As I said the project using xib files, there is no storyboard. Also myMainViewController is created programatically. is anyway I can set that property(as initialViewController) in the code?